# Handling HTTP requests with same content

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a `WebAPI` project that accepts XMLs coming in from external service and inserts them into `SQL Server` DB. The external service always sends out the latest state about the item, so given the example (Id element has always the same value within one XML):

First post:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Content>AB</Content>
        <Other>qwe</Other>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Content>CD</Content>
        <Other>qwe</Other>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Second post:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Content>AB</Content>
        <Other>rty</Other>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Content>CD</Content>
        <Other>qwe</Other>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Content>FG</Content>
        <Other>qwe</Other>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

So with first post I am getting 2 items and insert them into DB. Now with second, I see that AB-qwe has changed to AB-rty - I need to update this record; CD-qwe has not changed - nothing is needed; There is also a new one that needs to get inserted. There is also a case where a item no longer exists means I need to delete it.

What I am doing to achieve this is that I simply delete everything I got and insert the latest state.

```
    private static void AddOrUpdate(CancellationToken ct, string raw)
    {
        try
        {
            var items = Utils.DeserializeObject<Items>(raw);
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                var existingItems = context.Items.Where(r => r.Id == items.First().Id);
                foreach (var existing in existingItems)
                {
                    context.Items.Remove(existing);
                }
                foreach (var item in items.Item)
                {
                    context.Items.Add(new Item
                    {
                         //... skipped
                    });
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle
        }
    }
```

This approach is working for me, but I am generating a lot of overhead because actually the items very rarely change. Most of the time I get the exact same XML. So the question is that how could I understand if I already have handeled the item that is coming in? One idea I had was to take a checksum from each object and maintain them in some list, so when object comes in, take checksum, see if this one is processed, if so, return, else do this delete-insert cycle. This should be way faster than doing the DB routine every time. The problem with this is that when the IIS app pool gets recycled, I will lose my list and have to start over. How would you handle a situation such as mine?

### EDIT:

I am not inserting XMLs into Db, but the XML is deserialized into a object and that object represents the `entity model`, such as:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    [Index("idx_item_id")] 
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ItemId{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Content")]
    [Index("idx_content_bla")]
    public string Content{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Other")]
    public string OtherStuff{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what format do you insert in db?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution for your approach is to some sort of caching. For example you can use [memcache](http://memcached.org/)

It will preserve the data even after app poll recycle and also you can spread this operation across more processes or more machines.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply save the checksums to a file living in a well known location. When the AppPool gets recycled, you just load the previously saved checksums and keep going. When a new checksum arrives, you append the checksum to the file.

The only tricky part of that solution is having the correct permissions for the AppPool identity, but if you save in the `%AppData%` folder you should be fine.